# Why are two different window functions giving different sorted results?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I'm trying to add two window functions to my query. One is calculating a rolling total per customer and the other is simply adding a row number per customer.

When the rolling sum is working perfectly fine the row numbers are not sorted correctly. I like to add a descending row number so I can keep all row numbers 1 for each customer, in which i'd like to find the total for that customer.

I'm working in Snowflake SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    customer_id INTEGER
    ,txn_date DATE
    ,txn_type VARCHAR(10)
    ,txn_amount INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO transactions (customer_id, txn_date, txn_type, txn_amount) 
VALUES
('1', '2020-01-02', 'deposit',  '312'),
('1', '2020-01-02', 'deposit', '312'),
('1', '2020-03-05', 'purchase', '612'), 
('1', '2020-03-05', 'purchase', '612'), 
('1', '2020-03-17', 'deposit', '324'),  
('1', '2020-03-17', 'deposit', '324'),
('1', '2020-03-19', 'purchase', '664'), 
('1', '2020-03-19', 'purchase', '664');
```

This is the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT 
  customer_id
  ,txn_type
  ,txn_date
  ,txn_amount
  ,CASE WHEN txn_type = 'deposit'
        THEN txn_amount
        ELSE txn_amount * -1
   END AS new_amount
  ,SUM(new_amount) OVER (
   PARTITION BY customer_id
   ORDER BY customer_id, txn_date
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY customer_id
   ORDER BY customer_id, txn_date DESC) AS rn
FROM
  transactions
ORDER BY
  customer_id
  ,txn_date;
```

And its getting me these results:

| customer_id | txn_type | txn_date | txn_amount | new_amount | running_total | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-01-02 | 312 | 312 | 312 | 7 |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-01-02 | 312 | 312 | 624 | 8 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-05 | 612 | -612 | 12 | 5 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-05 | 612 | -612 | -600 | 6 |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-03-17 | 324 | 324 | -276 | 3 |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-03-17 | 324 | 324 | 48 | 4 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-19 | 664 | -664 | -616 | 1 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-19 | 664 | -664 | -1280 | 2 |

While I would expect this:

| customer_id | txn_type | txn_date | txn_amount | new_amount | running_total | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-01-02 | 312 | 312 | 312 | **8** |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-01-02 | 312 | 312 | 624 | **7** |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-05 | 612 | -612 | 12 | **6** |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-05 | 612 | -612 | -600 | **5** |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-03-17 | 324 | 324 | -276 | **4** |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-03-17 | 324 | 324 | 48 | **3** |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-19 | 664 | -664 | -616 | **2** |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-19 | 664 | -664 | -1280 | **1** |

So what am I doing wrong here?

Eventually I'd like to partition the row number not only by customer ID but also by month so I can fetch the latest record for each month and see what the running_total is.

Comment: If your logic can result in more than one candidate row then the results are indeterminate. So, for example, if you have 2 records with the same id and date you cannot determine in which order they will be returned - and that order can change each time you run the query

Comment: Use another column to sequence your transactions by customer. Like a trans_id column that increases by date. So this customer would have trans_id values of 1 thru 8. Then change to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id, tran_id DESC) AS rn` will get you the desired output. Basically, find a way to de-dupe in a way that works for you.

Comment: OK. I did not get a field with a unique ID. Would it be best to create a CTE with the row number first and afterwards add the rolling sum using that row number in the order by? It's just for a practice challenge so no need to add a transaction ID of some sorts to the database itself.

Comment: That might work or just create the same issue. Perhaps just use a CTE to create a number that represents a sequenced id and then use that new column in the 2nd windows function. Try both methods and see if both work.

Comment: OK. Can you give me advice on how to create a sequenced id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have duplicate data you will get inconsistent results. Here's a method of creating a pseudo transaction id in the CTE, and then reference this pseudo id within your second windows function of the main query.

```
with cte as (
 select 
  customer_id
  ,txn_type
  ,txn_date
  ,txn_amount
  ,CASE WHEN txn_type = 'deposit'
        THEN txn_amount
        ELSE txn_amount * -1
   END AS new_amount
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (
   partition by customer_id 
   order by customer_id, txn_date) as trans_id
  from transactions
)
select 
 customer_id 
 ,txn_type
 ,txn_date
 ,txn_amount
 ,new_amount
 ,SUM(new_amount) OVER (
   PARTITION BY customer_id
   ORDER BY customer_id, txn_date
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY customer_id
   ORDER BY customer_id, trans_id DESC) AS rn
from cte
order by 
 customer_id, 
 rn desc;
```

Output:

| CUSTOMER_ID | TXN_TYPE | TXN_DATE | TXN_AMOUNT | NEW_AMOUNT | RUNNING_TOTAL | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-01-02 | 312 | 312 | 312 | 8 |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-01-02 | 312 | 312 | 624 | 7 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-05 | 612 | -612 | 12 | 6 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-05 | 612 | -612 | -600 | 5 |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-03-17 | 324 | 324 | -276 | 4 |
| 1 | deposit | 2020-03-17 | 324 | 324 | 48 | 3 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-19 | 664 | -664 | -616 | 2 |
| 1 | purchase | 2020-03-19 | 664 | -664 | -1280 | 1 |

And if that's your desired route, then you could simply the main query which calculates the running total with the following because you no longer have duplicates to worry about:

```
,SUM(new_amount) OVER (
 PARTITION BY customer_id
 ORDER BY customer_id, trans_id) AS running_total
```

Comment: I don’t believe that this will solve the issue as the window function in the CTE still produces an indeterminant output if there are multiple records with the same customer_id and txn_date

Comment: @NickW This solution was tested (with the sample data provided by the OP) and proven to work in Snowflake prior to posting.